# Error serializing view model: "Type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper' cannot be serialized."

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Here is my view model:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int VendorId { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase SpreadsheetFile { get; set; }       

    public IEnumerable<Vendor> Vendors { get; set; }        
}
```

I'm loading my view model up with data and passing it to a view and serializing it:

```
@Html.Serialize("MyModel", myViewModel)
```

but I'm getting this error

> **Type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.**

I'm not sure how to mark something with the DataContractAttribute. Is there a way to mark the HttpPostedFileBase property as unserializeable?

Comment: `HttpPostedFileBase` is an abstract class, so you'd probably have to create an implementation to have something serializable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try marking it [NonSerialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx).

```
[Serializable]
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int VendorId { get; set; }

    [NonSerialized]
    public HttpPostedFileBase SpreadsheetFile { get; set; }       

    public IEnumerable<Vendor> Vendors { get; set; }        
}
```

Comment: There's no `NonSerializable` attribute, I tried adding `NonSerialized`, and I get a compilation error saying: Attribute 'NonSerialized' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'field' declarations.

Comment: My bad. Google being too helpful. I searched for NonSerializableAttribute, and the top result went to NonSerializedAttribute.

Comment: Attribute 'NonSerialized' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'field' declarations thrown in compile time

Answer (score 0):

Change the SpreadsheetFile to a property with a backing field and mark the backing field NonSerialized

```
[NonSerialized]
private HttpPostedFileBase _spreadSheetFile;
public HttpPostedFileBase SpreadsheetFile {
    get { return _spreadSheetFile; } 
    set { _spreadSheetFile = value; }
}
```

The serializer will respect the atrribute on the backing field. Even auto-implemented properties have a backing field generated by the compiler. Serializers use the backing field, not the property.